# Set cookie value get lost after redirecting to page on the same app domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, authentication, webforms

My web app based on.NET/Webforms does not work like expected because of losing value of set cookie after redirecting to page on the same app domain. But this app worked perfect before. The problem is as following:

Set cookie on Login:

```
    protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            . . .
            string userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eng);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                     1,
                     UserName.Text,
                     DateTime.Now,
                     DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
                     false,
                     userData);
                    string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                    HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
                    Response.Redirect("~/View_Id");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                FailureText.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            }
     }
```

Setting a new cookie works fine, but the value get lost after redirecting. The value will be need on `Global.FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)`.

Answer (score 0):

ok fox, after reading about cookie i found out, that the set user data was too big (more than allowed 4k) - hence the set cookie value will be lost or overrided with null. Reducing the size of user data to the max. limit of 4k is the solution!